# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) RVM 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, activesupport

I have an error when running the rails server

> ```
> SystemStackError in UsuariosController#login
> stack level too deep
>
> activesupport (3.1.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396
> ```

I currently have this code in production, but I must perform a maintenance on the server and I am testing on another server, therefore, install everything again

> Ubuntu 16.04 RVM Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.1.12 Datamapper Nginx

I have bundle install without problems, the gems installed, same code, same facilities, but I can't find the error.

Follow up with a code that I found and generate the txt but I can't understand the lines of code

> Started GET "/usuarios/login" for 190.82.72.125 at 2019-10-18 18:35:09 -0300
>     Processing by UsuariosController#login as HTML
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1088ms
>   SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
>
> Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (8.9ms)
>   Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (118.1ms)
>   Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (149.1ms)

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer. You need to provide the full stack trace and the relevant code that triggered the exception. Not the code from ActiveSupport, _your_ code that is calling the code in ActiveSupport, and the stack trace will show what file and what line that is. See [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more.

Comment: Dude, I have a txt with 1200,000 lines, where I could upload that to review

Comment: I don't know where this 1.2m line long file comes into the picture. I said to post your stack trace and the lines from your code that the stack trace references. That should be 20 lines at most.

Comment: Since you're using Ruby 1.9.3 you won't be able to see the stack trace -- oops! I suggest reading [this](https://gist.github.com/jbgo/4493822) so you can figure out how to get the stack trace displayed and track down the source of the error. Chances are it's in your `usuarios/login` controller action's callbacks, but without seeing that controller class it's hard to say.